# What Is The Best Software to Measure Influence on Social Media?

Tags: facebook, social-networks, twitter, instagram, linkedin

Now that [klout.com](https://www.lithium.com/products/klout) is no more, I'm curious what the professionals are recommending as an influence measurement web app for social media accounts. By influence I am referring to the ability of a social media account to influence or drive the flow of narratives on social media.

To my view, the ideal social influence measurement web app should take the following variables into account:

1. **Engagement NOT Followers** - focus on engagement with posts rather than number of followers.
2. **Comments Highest, Likes Lowest** -  relative scoring scheme for likes (the lowest), shares/retweets (medium) and comments (the highest), based on the measure of personal engagement. A like is between two people and essentially just a mouse click, a share is exposed to multiple people yet essentially is just a mouse click, a comment is exposed to multiple and require actual typing.
3. **Quotations** - the times someone's posts have been quoted by others and/or the number of people adding a person to a list (Twitter only).
4. **Number of Followers** - as a factor but not the most important

There are several alternatives out-there like [klear.com](https://klear.com/) and [go.kred](https://www.go.kred) which is supposed to relaunch in few days...

Which is your recommendation?

Comment: Can you define social media? I.e which ones interest yo? Only those in the tags? Pinterest, Tiktok, others?